# how to get data from a query that return a 3 dimension array and set values on a twig view in symfony 3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

im working on a project with symfony3 and im beginner at this framework 
this is my problem 
i have a table in data base called groupe wher i have a colum called member in which i have  stored the id's of members in this group
[table database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnahj.png)

in the first step i would like to get those ids from the groupe table and then explode them to send queries to my database to get the nom,prenomand the profile pic that correspand to the id send 
so i have made two action in my repository

this is my first action in my repository which allow me to get string of id from table membre in my  database

```
    public function getmemberstring($id){

    $membres = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT g.membres FROM GroupGroupBundle:Groupe g  
            WHERE g.id =:id')
        ->setParameter('id',$id);



    return $membres->getResult();

}
```

and this is my seccond function in my repository that allows me to extract id from the previous string and send request to database to get the information that i want

```
  public function getmemberlist($list){

    $memberId = explode('-',$list);


            $membres = array();
          foreach($memberId as $value){
                $nom = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('SELECT m.nom FROM MainBundle:Member m
                    WHERE m.id =:id')
                    ->setParameter('id',$value);
                 $nom = $nom->getResult();

              $prenom = $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createQuery('SELECT m.prenom FROM MainBundle:Member m
                    WHERE m.id =:id')
                  ->setParameter('id',$value);
              $prenom = $prenom->getResult();


              $pic = $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createQuery('SELECT m.profile_pic FROM MainBundle:Member m
                    WHERE m.id =:id')
                  ->setParameter('id',$value);
              $pic = $pic->getResult();


              array_push($membres,$nom,$prenom,$pic);


          }

    return $membres;

}
```

this is my controller

```
   public function membreGroupeAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $str = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->findOneBy(array('id'=>1));
    $member = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->getmemberlist($str->getMembres());



    return $this->render('@GroupGroup/layout/membres.html.twig',array("mem"=>$member));

}
```

this is my twig view wher i want to show my send by the controller

```
  {% extends '@GroupGroup/Group/groupe_mur_base.html.twig' %}
  {% block panel %}
  {% for i in  mem %}
    {% for j in i %}
      {% for t in j  %}
        {{ t }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
 <div class="jumbotron list-content" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item title">
            Liste des Membres
        </li>
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item text-left" id="listmembre"      style="display: block;">
            <div class="image">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/User_for_snippets.png">
                <span id="membername">Juan guillermo cuadrado</span>
                <div><button id="btnajout" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button></div>

            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
        </li>
```

this is how my data appears in my template i want to style them and to get only the 3 item for each user separated in li list like the template below[my template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLcv7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in one query

```
public function getmemberlist($list){

    $memberId = explode('-',$list);

    $membres = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT m.nom, m.prenom, m.profile_pic
             FROM MainBundle:Member m
             WHERE m.id IN(:id)'
        )
        ->setParameter('id',array_values($memberId))
        ->getResult()
    ;            

    return $membres;
}
```

or even better in a repository

```
public function getmemberlist($list){

    $memberId = explode('-',$list);

    $membres = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->where('m.id IN(:id)')
        ->setParameter('id',array_values($memberId))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;            

    return $membres;
}
```

This way you will get a one dimension array containing all the users in your group.

Your twig

```
{% extends '@GroupGroup/Group/groupe_mur_base.html.twig' %}
    {% block panel %}
        <div class="jumbotron list-content" style="display: block;">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li href="#" class="list-group-item title">
                    Liste des Membres
                </li>
                {% for m in mem %}
                    <li href="{{ path('your_path_to_member_details') }}" class="list-group-item text-left" id="listmembre"      style="display: block;">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ asset(m.profile_pic) }}"/>
                            <span class="membername">
                                {{ m.prenom }} {{ m.nom }}
                            </span> 
                        </div>
                    <div class="break"></div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div>
            <button id="btnajout" class="btn btn-primary">
                Ajouter
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Looking at your code it seems your french or belgian, you should go on [OpenClassrooms Symfony Tutoriel](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony) to learn how to develop with Symfony

Comment: Your method return only for one id how can i loop through other ids from the string that i get from my base

Comment: I updated my answer according to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255070/symfony2-doctrine-querybuilder-where-in). It seems to work differently with array and ArrayCollection

Comment: Thanks i will try this

Comment: this method works but im stuck in th twig view i cant access to the key of each array

Comment: I modify my answer to include modifcations for your twig