# Doctrine Query Builder: multiple parameterized fields, such as (a.field1, a.field2) IN ((1,1), (2, 2))

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How do I build a query so that I can parameterize multiple fields in the QueryBuilder like this:

```
$qb->andWhere('(a.field1, a.field2) IN ((1, 1), (2, 2))');
```

The above example gives me an error:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 84: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

I'm using Doctrine 2.6.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Doctrine querybuilder where IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255070/symfony2-doctrine-querybuilder-where-in)

Comment: Or, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536190/doctrine-2-where-in-clause-using-a-collection-of-entities Oh, and that's really about WHERE IN, trying to do two in one go like that simply won't work. Use `where->(field1..., andWhere->(field2...`

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The possible duplicate question does not address multiple corresponding fields.

Answer (score 0):

Think the main part about how to use `WHERE IN` has been answered many times.

Trying to combine two criteria like that won't work. Same way this SQL would never work:

```
select * from users where (id, email) IN ((1, 2), ('foo@gmail.com', 'bar@gmail.com'));
```

You would write that as

```
select * from users where id IN(1,2) AND email IN('foo@gmail.com', 'bar@gmail.com');
```

As of 2.5 I believe you would want:

```
$qb->andWhere('a.field1 IN (:fieldOneValues)')
  ->andWhere('a.field2 IN (:fieldTwoValues)')
  ->setParameter('fieldOneValues', $fieldOneValues)
  ->setParameter('fieldTwoValues', $fieldTwoValues);
```

**UPDATE:**

Now I understand better. The SQL I shared shows I didn't understand that syntax. How many values are you testing against? Could you approach it like?

```
(a.field1 = 1 AND a.field2 = 1) OR (a.field1 = 2 AND a.field2 = 2)
```

Doing an `explain` on the query it actually seemed like MySQL leveraged keys much better with this method.

Comment: That query could create unexpected results though. Consider these two queries, which would produce different results: "select * from tbl 
WHERE (a, b) IN ((2, 1), (1, 2))" versus "select * from tbl WHERE a in (2, 1) AND b in (1, 2)"

Comment: I'm confused. That first one seems like invalid syntax. Are you looking for `OR` as opposed to `AND`? You understand grouping with parentheses?

Comment: Wow, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706196/mysql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause Swear I got error about "two operands" when I tested it. Well learn something new every day. Can say in over 20 years of development I've never made use of that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get Doctrine to work with multiple columns for IN's so that it doesn't return unexpected results. :D

Comment: Doctrine isn't gonna play well with that. I'd just write raw SQL and use `RSM` if needing actual entities to be returned.

Comment: I may just go w/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/44706402/6950851 and translate it to DQL.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around that logic... both fields being in both sets right? Not working like I would expect. Sorry this answer is not helpful. Good luck! ... oh I get it now... and why I got the operand error, not what I anticipated at first